# Should I flag a question for a mod to add a status-* tag?

Tags: discussion, flags, meta

I sometimes see questions (usually bug reports) where an issue is now fixed and [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) has not been added.

Should I flag these for moderator attention so they can add the requested tag to the question? Or should I just leave it and move on?

The message would be along the lines of `this question was [something], therefore the [tag:status-whatever] tag should be added`.

Of course I wouldn't do this if a mod has answered the question - I'd just comment on their answer to ask them to add the tag.

Note: I have flagged around 4 questions in the past, and they have been 'helpful', after 2 or 3 weeks, but I'm asking to see whether mods mind these (seemingly petty) flags :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, why not? Go ahead and flag.

> [image]

Though if the question is answered by the mod (which wasn't the case above) who accepted / rejected the feature request (or a bug), you can also comment on their answer.